# What is the correct definition of coNP/poly?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines

[Complexity Zoo](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:C#conppoly) defines coNP/poly as
Complement of NP/poly
Thanks to [Emil](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/6959/emil-je%c5%99%c3%a1bek), I understand it as
"the class of decision problems whose complement can be **solved** in polynomial time by a non-deterministic Turing machine that has access to a polynomial-bounded advice function."

(A polynomial-bounded advice function is a function $f$ that maps each positive integer $n$ to an advice string $f(n)$ of length polynomial in $n$. To be clear, the advice string depends only on $n$; it is independent of the input to the Turing machine.)

I don't clearly understand this definition. A decision problem is basically a yes/no question, and I suppose "solving a decision problem" means answering the yes/no question correctly. But, if that is the case, then solving a decision problem is same as solving the complement of the problem. So, I wonder
**What is the meaning of the word 'solve' in the definition of coNP/poly (or NP/poly)?**

I am also interested in whether we can define coNP/poly (or NP/poly) in terms of deterministic polynomial time verifiers (as in the definition of NP). The best I could come up with are the following.

*NP/poly* is the class of decision problems whose yes certificates can be verified in polynomial time by a (deterministic) Turing machine that has access to a polynomial-bounded advice function.

*coNP/poly* is the class of decision problems whose no certificates can be verified in polynomial time by a (deterministic) Turing machine that has access to a polynomial-bounded advice function.

**Are these definitions correct?**

Disclaimer: I have asked a [related question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/47920/47855) in cstheory.stackexchange. At the time of asking that question, I did not know that the problem is in my understanding of the definition. They recommended that I ask the question here. (I shall delete my other question if the only problem is my understanding of the definition).

Thank you

Comment: Do you understand the definition of NP/poly?  Do you know what "solve" means in that context?  If not, then you should make sure you understand that first before trying to tackle coNP/poly.  If yes, then you already know the answer to your question -- it means the same thing.

Comment: @D.W. I don't. I have modified the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that a [decision problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_problem) is a language $L \subseteq \{0,1\}^*$.  (This is the language of all words $w$ such that the answer to the yes/no question is "yes".)

In this context, a Turing machine solves a decision problem $L$ if $L$ is the language accepted by that Turing machine.  In other words, when run on input $w$, the Turing machine halts and accepts if $w \in L$, and halts and rejects if $w \notin L$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a doubt though. If $w\notin L$, the Turing machine need not halt, right? If the TM could probably not halt on no instances, then it doesn't solve the complement problem automatically (and hence solving a problem is different from solving the complement of the problem).

Comment: @CyriacAntony, I recommend that you get a good textbook on formal languages, as these are pretty basic questions that should be covered there.  See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_language#Definitions.